# Background Image for Scaffold

Tags: flutter, scaffold

I want to set the image as the background color for Scaffold. When setting an AppBar and bottom bar, using the decoration of the Container as the body of the scaffold doesn't cover the complete screen.

I want to show background for full screen.
Below is my Scaffold code:

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Image.asset('images/background.png').color,
      body: Container(
        decoration: defaultAppBoxDecoration(),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Text('Title here', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal),),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('images/star.png'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Image.asset('images/star.png')),
                  //  IconButton(icon: Image.asset('images/grid.png')),

        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child:           IconButton(icon: Image.asset('images/star.png')),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0, right: 4.0),
        height: 44.0 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(icon: Image.asset('images/star.png')),
          IconButton(icon: Image.asset('images/star.png')),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: Please refer to the image]

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try using `Stack` check the following sample:

```
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            "resources/background.png",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0.0,
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0, right: 4.0),
                height: 44.0 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.star)),
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.star)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              body: Text("Hello world"))
        ],
      );
    }
```

Comment: Scaffold.backgroundColor is what I missed. Thanks

Comment: it works but it blink for a while then loading image.

Comment: backgroundColor: Colors.transparent is the way

Comment: `@Kuldeep your blinking probably happened because you loaded image from somewhere else.. Loading image from flutter asset is instant and has no blinking.

Answer (score 27):

You can place your Scaffold inside Container with background image and use transparent color for Scaffold's body like this:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage("assets/bg.jpg"),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    body: Container(),
),);
```

Answer (score 10):

Setting the `backgroundColor:Colors.transparent` is the key you are missing.
[image]